# no output in vs code using python logging module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, logging, python-logging

I'm on Windows 10 using VS Code 1.73.1 and am retrofitting my program with the Python `logging` module. My program is generally functioning. The main thing I did is change all the print statements to `logger.debug` and I know the variable formatting needs to be changed from `{}` to `%s`. I also added the `encoding` flag to my file handler.

*A couple more things:*

1. When I run it from the VS Code command line, it does create a file with debug statements but does not display any output to the Terminal, Debug Console or Output windows.
2. When I use the `F5` function to run it, it does NOT create a file or display any console output anywhere.

`print('something')` works and displays in either the Terminal or Debug Console depending on the `launch.json` setting, but `logger.debug('something')` does not display in either console.

**My request/question:**  Using `logger.debug`, why is nothing printing to console, and no file is even created?

I also tried running the code below in its own separate `.py` file with the same problem: 
`print` displays to the Debug Console, but `logger.debug` does not.

Logging code block:

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Streaming Handler
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
# File Handler
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('download_shelf.log', encoding='utf-8')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.debug(f"Log messages:") ### `print` statement displays in either the Terminal 
                               ### or Debug Console depending on `launch.json` setting
```

I made sure my `launch.json` file was set up in the local `.vscode` folder (see bottom code section). However, I did have to manually create this file, then restarted VS Code. Information I found said there was a link in the Debug panel, which I know I've seen before. It wasn't there for this file.

My directory structure:

```
toplevel/
    .vscode/
        launch.json
    src/
        subdirectory/
           myfile.py
```

My `launch.json` file  contains `"console": "internalConsole"`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {"name":"Python: Current File",
        "type":"python",
        "request":"launch",
        "program":"${file}",
        // "console":"integratedTerminal",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "justMyCode":true
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: To start: why aren't you calling `logging.basicConfig` before you start manipulating loggers manually?

Comment: I actually started this "adventure" with a simple `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", filename='download_shelf.log', filemode='w', encoding='utf-8')` `logging.debug('simple message')`

Comment: Same problems. I did try running both versions from the VS Code terminal line, and it does create a file from there, either way. Hmm, realized I forgot to add that I'm using the `F5` function to run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After using a different logger example, I realized the problem was the Level setting in the first example I used had "INFO" and not "DEBUG" so nothing was showing up. Oops...

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
formatter =  logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s : %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console)

logger.debug('simple message')
```